# Number of times each weekday occurs between two dates

Tags: python, datetime

In Python, say we have two dates:

```
date_from = datetime.date(2014,02,8)
date_to   = datetime.date(2014,12,9)
```

and we need to count the number of times each weekday of the week occurs between these two days. What is a good way to approach this?

For example, if we have:

```
date_from = datetime.date(2014,11,30) # Sunday
date_to   = datetime.date(2014,12,9)  # Tuesday
```

The answer I am looking for is (with days of the week either in string or numeric form) is:

```
'Sunday': 2
'Monday': 2
'Tuesday': 2
'Wednesday': 1
'Thursday': 1
'Friday': 1
'Saturday': 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> weekdays = Counter()

>>> date_from = datetime.date(2014,11,30) # Sunday
>>> date_to   = datetime.date(2014,12,9)  # Tuesday

>>> for i in range((date_to - date_from).days+1):
...    weekdays[(date_from + datetime.timedelta(i))\
...                                  .strftime('%a')] += 1

>>> weekdays
Counter({'Sun': 2, 'Tue': 2, 'Mon': 2, 'Wed': 1, 'Fri': 1, 
         'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1})
```

Another take:

```
def dates_between(start, end):
    while start <= end:
        yield start
        start += datetime.timedelta(1)

def count_weekday(start, end):
    counter = Counter()
    for date in dates_between(start, end):
        counter[date.strftime('%a')] += 1
    return counter
```

Then:

```
>>> count_weekday(date_from, date_to)
Counter({
    'Sun': 2, 
    'Tue': 2, 
    'Mon': 2, 
    'Wed': 1, 
    'Fri': 1, 
    'Thu': 1, 
    'Sat': 1
})
```

[update]

Mark Ransom commented:

> There's really no need to count every single day individually.  ... I've already given upvotes to the people who did it better.

I'm sure there are many other ways to achieve the same result, but what is the point? Perhaps someone is worried about performance. I'm not - because:

- the difference between `O(n)` and `O(n log n)` is irrelevant for small values of n.
- as said by the venerable Donald Knuth: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".
- the answer to questions about performance is always "profile it" - more than once I was surprised for how unintuitive the results can be.

And after profiling, even if other algorithm is a few milliseconds faster:

- is the difference in performance relevant for the application?
- is the code easier to reason about?
- can you make sure that all corner cases are covered?

The trade of between raw performance and simpler design is one I'm willing to take most of the time.

Comment: There's really no need to count every single day individually.

Comment: @MarkRansom even if you are right your comment is not very constructive. I don't care enough to write a more efficient solution - if you do, write your own answer. :-)

Comment: The comment wasn't meant for you, it was meant for others looking at this answer. And no need to write my own, I've already given upvotes to the people who did it better.

Comment: The other answers aren't O(n log n), they're O(1) - a much more significant difference. And even if it doesn't matter in this particular case, I don't think it's a good idea to get in the habit of writing slow code. `n` has a habit of getting much larger than you expected it to, or maybe this code will be called from another loop where its effect will be multiplied. I find myself working with such code every day.

Answer (score 2):

For you problem I'd use the answer of @JonKiparsky. He told anything you need:

```
>>> date_from = datetime.date(2014,02,8)
>>> date_to   = datetime.date(2014,12,9)
>>> td = date_to - date_from
>>> td.days
304
>>>
```

You need just to use it rationally: in this delta you have 304 days, it is 304/7 = 43 full weeks and 3 days more. So first 3 days (date_from one and 2 more) will be counted as 44, others are 43.

It may be easier than 2x2!:

```
days = {
    0: 0,
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0,
    4: 0,
    5: 0,
    6: 0,
}
full_weeks = 304 / 7   # 43
remainder = 304 % 7    # 3
first_day = date_from.weekday()
for day in days.keys():
    days[day] = full_weeks
for i in range(0, remainder):
    days[(first_day + i) % 7] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Corrected answer:

Subtract date_from from date_to to get a number of days total. Divide by seven to get the number of weeks - one of each day_of_week for each week, obviously. Then add in any remaining weekdays:

```
>>> total_days = (date_to-date_from).days
>>> total_days
304
>>> weeks = total_days/7
>>> weeks
43
>>> days_of_week = {i:weeks for i in range (7)}
>>> if date_to.weekday() > date_from.weekday():
...   end_date = date_to.weekday()
... else:
...   end_date = date_to.weekday() +7
... 
>>> for i in range (date_from.weekday(), end_date + 1):
...   days_of_week[i %7] +=1
... 
>>> days_of_week
{0: 44, 1: 44, 2: 43, 3: 43, 4: 43, 5: 44, 6: 44}
```

Comment: I think the question was about counting the number of times each weekday occurs, not the total day count.

Comment: You should get in the habit of using `//` for integer division so you won't be surprised by Python 3 some day.

Comment: Meh. If I'm writing in 3, I use 3. If I'm writing in 2, I use 2. It's not that surprising.

Comment: Fair enough. But think of the Googlers who will find this answer 5 years from now.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, without using `Counter` would be:

```
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday',
        'Sunday']
day_counts = dict(zip(days, [0]*7))
this_day = date_from
td = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
while this_day <= date_to:
    day_counts[days[this_day.weekday()]] += 1
    this_day += td

>>> day_counts
{'Monday': 44, 'Tuesday': 44, 'Friday': 43, 'Wednesday': 43, 'Thursday': 43,
 'Sunday': 44, 'Saturday': 44}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a counter that tracks the day of the week, one day at a time, from the *start* until the *end* date.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from collections import Counter

start=datetime(2014, 11, 30)
until=datetime(2014, 12, 9)
differences = [start + timedelta(i) for i in xrange((until - start).days + 1)]
print dict(Counter(d.strftime('%A') for d in differences))
```

The output is:

```
{'Sunday': 2, 'Monday': 2, 'Tuesday': 2, 'Friday': 1, 'Wednesday': 1, 'Thursday': 1, 'Saturday': 1}
```

Comment: This solution is very concise, and I considered using a generator expression also, but many people say you should not use a generator expression or list comprehension just for the side effects because it can hurt legibility. But for counters it is so tempting... :-)